# How to access database in Android virtual machine?

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui

For a MAUI program I want to use SQLite. How to connect Android virtual machine and IOS virtual machine to my database? I have `MyDbContext:DbContext` to create the database using:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

In my last program I used:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
```

which failed with a "Cannot open" exception. How should I modify `MyDbContext` (or MauiProgram.cs) to ensure proper connection?

```
public class MyDbContext:DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public MyDbContext()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Configure joining entity
        modelBuilder.Entity<SelectedCourse>().ToTable("SelectedCourse");
        modelBuilder.Entity<SelectedCourse>().HasKey(sc => new { sc.Neptun, sc.Id });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SelectedCourse>().HasOne<Student>(sc => sc.Student)
            .WithMany(s => s.SelectedCourses)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.Neptun);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SelectedCourse>().HasOne<Course>(sc => sc.Course)
            .WithMany(s => s.SelectedCourses)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.Id);
        //-------------------------------------------------
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasKey(s => s.Neptun);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(s => s.Name).IsRequired(required: true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(s => s.Password).IsRequired(required: true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(s => s.Email).IsRequired(required: true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(s => s.AdmissionTime).IsRequired(required: true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasData(new[]
        {
            new Student(){Neptun="ABC123",Name="Jhin",Password="Jhin123",Email="jhin123@gmail.com",AdmissionTime=new DateTime(2019,9,01)}
        });
        //-------------------------------------------------
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired(required: true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().Property(c => c.Credit).IsRequired(required: true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().Property(c => c.Room).IsRequired(required: true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().Property(c => c.Limiting).IsRequired(required: true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().Property(c => c.CourseTime).IsRequired(required: true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().Property(c => c.Proffesor).IsRequired(required: true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasData(new[]
        {
            new Course(){ Id="aaaVIAUAC09",Name="Software Development Laboratory 1",Credit=4,Room="QBF232",Limiting=40,CourseTime="K:14:15-18:00",Proffesor="aaa"},
            new Course(){ Id="aaaVIAUAC02",Name="Client Side Technologies",Credit=4,Room="QBF15",Limiting=40,CourseTime="H:14:15-16:00",Proffesor="aaa"}
        });
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SelectedCourse> SelectedCourses { get; set; }
}
```

MauiProgram.cs:

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=data.db"));
#if DEBUG
    builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: `optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={dbPath}");`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=android#app-data-directory